# When using fork, scanf in parent reads input twice

Tags: c, fork, scanf

When program is reading input from file like this `./a.out < inputFile` after fork all input is printed twice to output like there would be no `exit(0)` in child of `fork`. My expectation was that everything would be printed only once, since program is only printing in parent, not child. Why does that happen?

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <wait.h>

int main() {
    char currentChar;
    int counter = 0;
    while (scanf("%c", &currentChar) != EOF) {
        printf("%c", currentChar);
        fflush(stdout);
        counter++;
        if (counter == 10) {
            // all characters after 10 characters are printed twice
            int pid = fork();
            if (pid == 0) {
                // child;
                exit(0);
            } else {
                // parent;
                int status;
                waitpid(pid, &status, 0);
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What's your OS?  If it's Linux, try running under `strace` and see what the child process is doing:  `strace -f -o /some/output/file ./a.out < inputFile`.  Your output file will contain all the system calls both processes make.  Your child process *should* just wind up exiting.

Comment: I ran strace and managed to find the problem. The problem was that the input was buffered, placing setbuf(stdin, NULL) at the beginning of main() solved the problem. Thank you so much